# rsync checksum not working for folders

Tags: rsync

I have an rsync command

```
rsync -azvh --checksum --delete --exclude '.git' fordeploy/ target/
```

This works well and ignores files that have only a time stamp change. The problem I have is that the timestamps of my internal folders all change all the time, all of this gets synced across, I don't want this to happen.

I tried --ignore-times but that didn't work either.

Q. How do I get rsync to ignore folder time stamps as well?

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER:** `--checksum` only applyes to files. This means that, if timestamp changes, directory attributes are always retransmitted.

**LONG ANSWER:** a directory really is a special kind of file. If anything changes inside the directory (ie: a file timestamp is updated, a file is added, etc), the on-disk directory content changes as well. This meas that `rsync` **must** retransmit it to give you a consistent copy/backup.